# C++ win32 api double-buffering example help please

Tags: c++, winapi, double-buffering

So, I know that people talk about double buffering on different posts, but whenever I try it I get a black screen! this is because the examples I see (I need examples) don't program the way i do - like with different libraries. I only use  at the moment. anyways, here is the initial program piece which badly flickers:

```
void drawRed (HDC hdc)
{
  HDC hdcMemory;
  hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

  while (1==1){

  SelectObject(hdcMemory, redmask);
  BitBlt(hdc, 132, 132, 128, 128, hdcMemory, 0, 0, SRCAND);

  SelectObject(hdcMemory, red);
  BitBlt(hdc, 132, 132, 128, 128, hdcMemory, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);
  }

  DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
}
```

and I looked and tried this:

```
void drawRed (HDC hdc)
{
 HDC hDC = GetDC(hnd);

 HDC hdcMemory;
 hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

 HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
 HBITMAP hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC,100,100);
 HBITMAP hOldBmp =  (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC,hMemBmp);

 SelectObject(hdcMemory, hbmMem);
 BitBlt(hDC, -100, -100, 128, 128, memDC, 0, 0, SRCAND);

 SelectObject(hdcMemory, red);
 BitBlt(hDC, -100, -100, 128, 128, memDC, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);

 SelectObject(hdcMemory, red);
 BitBlt(hDC, 132, 132, 128, 128, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

 DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
}
```

and this just shows a black box. I don't know how I'm supposed to do it, so can you change the original code block to be double-buffered? thanks!

I use dev-c++ ide.

Comment: You have one too many memory DCs You selecting objects (bitmaps, etc) into `hdcMemory`, but are BitBlt'ing with `memDC`. Pick one, and lose the other. I *think* you're trying to create two on purpose, but in that case your hDC shouldn't be used at all until the bitter end. (and you need to setup two compatible bitmaps; not one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MFC you can use class **CMemDC** by  Keith Rule. There is good article about this class with example - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC

Similar class included in MFC Feature Pack - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308997.aspx